# ARC Welder doesnt run android application

Tags: android, automatic-ref-counting

I have been trying to run my android apps through ARC welder splash screen comes but it doesn't run. I have even tried running facebook app in it but that also gives error. Is there anything special to be done to make apps up and running in ARC Welder??

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: "Kill page" image comes. It doesn't have any message.